# How to reverse the order of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I've endlessly looked for this and somehow nothing has solved this *simple* problem.

I have a dataframe called Prices in which there are 4 columns, one of which is a list of historical dates - the other 3 are lists of prices for products.

```
1   10/10/2016  53.14   50.366  51.87
2   07/10/2016  51.93   49.207  50.38
3   06/10/2016  52.51   49.655  50.98
4   05/10/2016  51.86   49.076  50.38
5   04/10/2016  50.87   48.186  49.3
6   03/10/2016  50.89   48.075  49.4
7   30/09/2016  50.19   47.384  48.82
8   29/09/2016  49.81   46.924  48.4
9   28/09/2016  49.24   46.062  47.65
10  27/09/2016  46.52   43.599  45.24
```

The list is 252 prices long. How can I have my output stored with the latest date at the bottom of the list and the corresponding prices listed with the latest prices at the bottom of the list?

Comment: If `df` is your `data.frame`, the date column is called `date` and you want to sort your dataset by date, just try `df[order(df$date),]`.

Comment: Also make sure your `date` column is set `as.Date`

Comment: The OP's date is not a `Date` object, unfortunately @Sotos. It'd be an ISO format string if it were. I'm super curious why the display order matters, though (since we may be able to help with whatever processing they want to do which relies on order). But, since the OP seems to have it in reverse order already and knows the # of rows `df[252:1,]` would also work.

Comment: Calculation of Bollinger Bands using Bbands in the TTR package is the reason. Seems that the function is calculating from the bottom up - please correct me if i'm wrong?

Comment: Honestly I solved this by changing my SQL query to my database... BUT I still want to know how to do this in R. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: If the problem is that the column with dates is in string format, you can do this using @nicola's solution with a tweak: `df[order(as.Date(df$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")),]`.

Comment: As many users below have suggested, you can use tidyverse's `arrange` function. However, I agree with nicola's suggestion to arrange by data, and NOT by row number.

Comment: FWIW, the `data.table` package handles this nicely. Assuming the sort column is named *date* and is class *Date*:
`dt <- data.table(aa); setkey(dt, date); dt[(.N:1)]`

Answer (score 37):

Another `tidyverse` solution and I think the simplest one is:

`df %>% map_df(rev)`

or using just `purrr::map_df` we can do `map_df(df, rev)`.

Comment: Should be the selected answer IMO.

Comment: Agreed...I would give more up votes if I could

Comment: This answer generates an error for matrix columns (which are, admittedly, a bit wierd). For example: `tibble(a=1:2, b=matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)) %>% map_df(rev) # error`.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want to reverse the order of the rows in a dataframe, you can do the following:

```
df<- df[seq(dim(df)[1],1),]
```

Comment: Nice solution. But you do not need `seq` here. It will only slow your code down.

Answer (score 16):

Yet another `tidyverse` solution is:

```r
df %>% arrange(desc(row_number()))
```

Comment: This should not be overlooked, due to its simplicity!

Comment: Note that this answer works for matrix-valued columns. For example: `tibble(a=1:2, b=matrix(1:6, nrow = 2)) %>% arrange(desc(row_number()))`.

Answer (score 15):

Just for completeness sake. There is actually no need to call `seq` here. You can just use the `:`-R-logic:

```
### Create some sample data
n=252
sampledata<-data.frame(a=sample(letters,n,replace=TRUE),b=rnorm(n,1,0.7),
                       c=rnorm(n,1,0.6),d=runif(n))

### Compare some different ways to reorder the dataframe
myfun1<-function(df=sampledata){df<-df[seq(nrow(df),1),]}
myfun2<-function(df=sampledata){df<-df[seq(dim(df)[1],1),]}
myfun3<-function(df=sampledata){df<-df[dim(df)[1]:1,]}
myfun4<-function(df=sampledata){df<-df[nrow(df):1,]}

### Microbenchmark the functions


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfun1(),myfun2(),myfun3(),myfun4(),times=1000L)
    Unit: microseconds
         expr    min     lq      mean  median      uq      max neval
     myfun1() 63.994 67.686 117.61797 71.3780 87.3765 5818.494  1000
     myfun2() 63.173 67.686  99.29120 70.9680 87.7865 2299.258  1000
     myfun3() 56.610 60.302  92.18913 62.7635 76.9155 3241.522  1000
     myfun4() 56.610 60.302  99.52666 63.1740 77.5310 4440.582  1000
```

The **fastest way** in my trial here was to use `df<-df[dim(df)[1]:1,]`. However using `nrow` instead of `dim` is only slightly slower. Making this a question of personal preference.

Using `seq` here definitely slows the process down.

*UPDATE September 2018:*

From a speed view there is little reason to use `dplyr` here. For maybe 90% of users the basic R functionality should suffice. The other 10% need to use `dplyr` for querying a database or need code translation into another language.

```
## hmhensen's function
dplyr_fun<-function(df=sampledata){df %>% arrange(rev(rownames(.)))}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfun3(),myfun4(),dplyr_fun(),times=1000L)
Unit: microseconds
        expr    min      lq      mean  median      uq    max neval
    myfun3()   55.8   69.75  132.8178  103.85  139.95 8949.3  1000
    myfun4()   55.9   68.40  115.6418  100.05  135.00 2409.1  1000
 dplyr_fun() 1364.8 1541.15 2173.0717 1786.10 2757.80 8434.8  1000
```

Comment: Your `dplyr` solution will not work as expected, because you are sorting by rownames which are of type `character`. So, ascending, you would have: "1", "10", "100", "2", etc...

Comment: @JamesHirschorn Not my solution. This is the dplyr solution from hmhensen. I upvoted your comment though

Comment: all of these solutions break for data.frames with zero rows

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to order the list by the vector you want to sort it by,

```
> data[order(data$Date), ]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Date                priceA priceB priceC
   <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2016-09-27 00:00:00   46.5   43.6   45.2
 2 2016-09-28 00:00:00   49.2   46.1   47.6
 3 2016-09-29 00:00:00   49.8   46.9   48.4
 4 2016-09-30 00:00:00   50.2   47.4   48.8
 5 2016-10-03 00:00:00   50.9   48.1   49.4
 6 2016-10-04 00:00:00   50.9   48.2   49.3
 7 2016-10-05 00:00:00   51.9   49.1   50.4
 8 2016-10-06 00:00:00   52.5   49.7   51.0
 9 2016-10-07 00:00:00   51.9   49.2   50.4
10 2016-10-10 00:00:00   53.1   50.4   51.9
```

Then if you are so inclined, you want to flip the order, reverse it,

```
> data[rev(order(data$Date)), ]
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Date                priceA priceB priceC
   <dttm>               <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2016-10-10 00:00:00   53.1   50.4   51.9
 2 2016-10-07 00:00:00   51.9   49.2   50.4
 3 2016-10-06 00:00:00   52.5   49.7   51.0
 4 2016-10-05 00:00:00   51.9   49.1   50.4
 5 2016-10-04 00:00:00   50.9   48.2   49.3
 6 2016-10-03 00:00:00   50.9   48.1   49.4
 7 2016-09-30 00:00:00   50.2   47.4   48.8
 8 2016-09-29 00:00:00   49.8   46.9   48.4
 9 2016-09-28 00:00:00   49.2   46.1   47.6
10 2016-09-27 00:00:00   46.5   43.6   45.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this in base R use:

```
df <- df[rev(seq_len(nrow(df))), , drop = FALSE]
```

All other base R solutions posted here will have problems in the edge cases of zero row data frames (`seq(0,1) == c(0, 1)`, that's why we use `seq_len`) or single column data frames (`data.frame(a=7:9)[3:1,] == 9:7`, that's why we use  `, drop = FALSE`).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to stick with base R, you could also use `lapply()`.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(df, rev))
```