# 3 layer Stacked histogram from already summarized counts using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plyr, lapply

I would like some help coloring a ggplot2 histogram generated from summarized data in a data.frame.

The dataset I'm using is the [R] build in (USArrests) dataset.

I'm trying to adapt the solution that was given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231109/stacked-histogram-from-already-summarized-counts-using-ggplot2) by arun.

The desired result is to make a histogram of "Crime" and color each bar according to the relative contribution of c("Assault", "Rape", "Murder").

The code:

```
attach(USArrests)

#Create vector SUM arrests per state
Crime <- with(USArrests, Murder+ Rape+ Assault)

#bind Vector Crime to dataframe USArrets and name it USArrests.transform
USArrests.transform <- cbind (USArrests, Crime)

#See if package is installed, and do if not
if (!require("ggplot2")) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
  library(ggplot2)
}

ggplot (data = USArrests.transform, aes(x= Crime)) + geom_histogram()
# get crime histogram plot and name it crime.plot
crime.plot <- ggplot (data = USArrests.transform, aes(x= Crime)) + geom_histogram()
# get data of crime plot: cols = count, xmin and xmax
crime.data <- ggplot_build(crime.plot)$data[[1]][c("count", "x", "xmin", "xmax")]
# add a id colum for ddply
crime.data$id <- seq(nrow(crime.data))

#See if package is installed, and do if not
if (!require("plyr")) {
  install.packages("plyr")
  library(plyr)
}

#Split data frame, apply function en return results in a data frame: ddply
crime.data.transform <- ddply(crime.data, .(id), function(x) {
  tranche <- USArrests.transform[USArrests.transform$Crime >= x$xmin & USArrests.transform$Crime <= x$xmax, ]
  if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c(x$x, 0, 0))
  crime.plot <- c(x=x$x, colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["Crime"] * x$count)
})

#See if package is installed, and do if not
if (!require("reshape2")) {
  install.packages("reshape2")
  library(reshape2)
}

crime.data.transform <- melt(crime.data.transform, id.var="id")
ggplot(data = crime.data.transform, aes(x=id, y=value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat="identity", group=1)
```

[Error]: The above gives the following error:

```
Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels"), .id, id_as_factor) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths
```

Subsequently the are errors in part after the reshape.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong and how it could be solved in the above example?

Comment: I'm currently reviewing your question. Have you tried using `dplyr` on this? Debug your example line by line and form the equivalent expression in dplyr. It should be much easier for yourself to understand what you are doing. `melt` and `plyr` is stuff for experts in R. I'm good and even I don't know `plyr`

Comment: No I have not tried using [tag:dplyr] The reason I opted for adjusting the answer (source mentioned above) is that in this example I will be adding 3 stacks on top of each other. In different scenarios I could have to stock even more that is the reason I started trying. It is no must to use [tag:melt] and, or [tag:plyer]. The question to answer is how to stack multiple (more than 2) data.frame columns in a histogram, where the frequency count (height) of the histogrambar represents the sum of the included data.frame columns... any answer to this is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long answer I felt like doing some code optimisation. Mostly the code is not yours, but even in arun's code I found some room for optimisation. Let's go through what I changed:

1. I removed your `attach` statement, because it was not needed and if you work with multiple datasets it is bad practise to use `attach` - mainly because you loose track of your data structures
2. If you create a sequence and the step is 1, just use `:` and not `seq`. I explained [here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975317/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-a-dataframe-in-r/46399010#46399010)
3. The error in your code: In `return(c(x$x, 0, 0))` there is one zero to little.
4. In addition you do not need `x$x` inside the `ddply`-function. Thus it should just be `return(c(0,0,0))` and in the next line it needs to be `c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]`. Otherwise R will plot all the `x` values as well.
5. Heck! You actually do not need `plyr` here. This `ddply`-function is just a simple loop over the rows of your `crime.data`-data.frame. That is something you can achieve using an `lapply`-loop

Here I maybe need to explain a bit: The `plyr`-package tried to overcome the shortcomings of the `apply`-family-functions. Except for `lapply`, their behaviour is rather unpredictable. Especially `sapply` might return anything from `vector` over `matrix` to `list`-objects. Only `lapply` is reliable - it always gives you a `list` result:

```
USArrests_sum <- cbind (USArrests, arrests=with(USArrests, Murder+ Rape+ Assault))

#See if package is installed, and do if not
if (!require("ggplot2")) {
  install.packages("ggplot2")
  library(ggplot2)
}

# get crime histogram plot and name it crime.plot
crime.plot <- ggplot (data = USArrests_sum, aes(x= arrests)) + geom_histogram()
crime_df <- ggplot_build(crime.plot)$data[[1]][c("count", "x", "xmin", "xmax")] # get data of crime plot: cols = count, xmin and xmax
crime_df$id = 1:nrow(crime_df) #add a id colum for ddply

#Split data frame, apply function en return results in a data frame: ddply
tranche_list<-lapply(1:nrow(crime_df), function(j) {
  myrows<-(USArrests_sum$arrests >= crime_df$xmin[j] & USArrests_sum$arrests <= crime_df$xmax[j])
  tranche <- USArrests_sum[myrows,]
  if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c('Murder'=0,'Assault'=0,'Rape'=0))
  crime.plot <- c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["arrests"] * crime_df$count[j])
})
```

The alternative is to use `dplyr` to transform your data, maybe somebody else feels like that. I prefer doing `base R`.

In the next step you use `reshape2`, the successor is `tidyr`. But actually the data structure is so simple. You can use `base R` if you like:

```
stack_df2<-data.frame(value=as.numeric(unlist(tranche_list)),
                      variable=names(unlist(tranche_list)),
                      id=rep(1:nrow(crime_df),each=3))

ggplot(data = stack_df2, aes(x=id, y=value)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=variable), stat="identity", group=1)
```

#### Appendix

I compared multiple functions with the `ddply`-solution:

```
plyr_fun<-function(){
  ddply(crime_df, .(id), function(x) {
    tranche <- USArrests_sum[USArrests_sum$arrests >= x$xmin & USArrests_sum$arrests <= x$xmax, ]
    if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c(0, 0,0))
    crime.plot <- c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["arrests"] * x$count)
  })
}

apply_fun2<-function(){
  res_mat<-t(apply(crime_df, 1, function(x) {
    tranche <- USArrests_sum[USArrests_sum$arrests >= x['xmin'] & USArrests_sum$arrests <= x['xmax'], ]
    if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c(0, 0,0))
    crime.plot <- c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["arrests"] * x['count'])
  }))
  colnames(res_mat)=c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")
}

lapply_fun3<-function(){
  tranche_list<-lapply(1:nrow(crime_df), function(j) {
    myrows<-(USArrests_sum$arrests >= crime_df$xmin[j] & USArrests_sum$arrests <= crime_df$xmax[j])
    tranche <- USArrests_sum[myrows,]
    if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c(0, 0,0))
    crime.plot <- c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["arrests"] * crime_df$count[j])
  })
  do.call(rbind,tranche_list)
}

lapply_fun<-function(){
  tranche_list<-lapply(1:nrow(crime_df), function(j) {
    myrows<-(USArrests_sum$arrests >= crime_df$xmin[j] & USArrests_sum$arrests <= crime_df$xmax[j])
    tranche <- USArrests_sum[myrows,]
    if(nrow(tranche) == 0) return(c('Murder'=0,'Assault'=0,'Rape'=0))
    crime.plot <- c(colSums(tranche)[c("Murder", "Assault", "Rape")]/colSums(tranche)["arrests"] * crime_df$count[j])
  })
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(apply_fun2(),lapply_fun3(),lapply_fun(),plyr_fun(),times=1000L)
Unit: milliseconds
          expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  apply_fun2() 5.2307 5.73340  7.169920  6.17165  7.27340  31.5333  1000
 lapply_fun3() 5.3633 5.98930  7.487173  6.40780  7.50115  37.1350  1000
  lapply_fun() 5.4470 5.99295  7.762575  6.43975  7.73060  82.2069  1000
    plyr_fun() 8.8593 9.83850 12.186933 10.54180 12.75880 192.6898  1000
```

Actually the `apply`-function is even faster than the `lapply`-solution. But readability is quite bad. Usually `data.table`-function are faster than the `apply` family, whereas `dplyr`-function run comparatively slow but have a good readability and are suitable for code-translations.

Just for fun - another benchmark of `tidyr` vs my base R solution:

```
tidyr_fun<-function(){
  crime_tranche<-do.call(rbind,tranche_list)
  stack_df <- gather(data.frame(crime_tranche,id=1:nrow(crime_df)), key=variable,value=value,-id)
}

base_fun<-function(){
  stack_df2<-data.frame(value=as.numeric(unlist(tranche_list)),
                        variable=names(unlist(tranche_list)),
                        id=rep(1:nrow(crime_df),each=3))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(tidyr_fun(),base_fun())
Unit: microseconds
expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
tidyr_fun() 1588.4 1869.45 2516.253 2302.35 2777.9 7671.3   100
base_fun()  286.7  367.40  530.104  454.85  612.8 3675.8   100

# In case you want to verify that the data is the same. identical(stack_df2$id[order(stack_df2$id,stack_df2$variable)],stack_df$id[order(stack_df$id,stack_df$variable)])
identical(stack_df2$value[order(stack_df2$id,stack_df2$variable)],stack_df$value[order(stack_df$id,stack_df$variable)])
identical(as.character(stack_df2$variable[order(stack_df2$id,stack_df2$variable)]),stack_df$variable[order(stack_df$id,stack_df$variable)])
```