# Reverse the order of some data frame columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a `data.frame` and I want to calculate a performance metric (e.g. a quantile). However some columns of the `data.frame` are with statistics that you would consider "negative" - an example:

```
r=seq(0,1,0.25)
apply(state.x77,2,function(x) quantile(x,probs = r))
     Population  Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad  Frost      Area
0%        365.0 3098.00      0.500  67.9600  1.400   37.80   0.00   1049.00
25%      1079.5 3992.75      0.625  70.1175  4.350   48.05  66.25  36985.25
50%      2838.5 4519.00      0.950  70.6750  6.850   53.25 114.50  54277.00
75%      4968.5 4813.50      1.575  71.8925 10.675   59.15 139.75  81162.50
100%    21198.0 6315.00      2.800  73.6000 15.100   67.30 188.00 566432.00
```

Income and life expectancy are positive. However, e.g. the murder rate is negative, the lower it is the better. I want exactly this result:

```
     Population  Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad  Frost      Area
0%        365.0 3098.00      2.800  67.9600 15.100   37.80 188.00   1049.00
25%      1079.5 3992.75      1.575  70.1175 10.675   48.05 139.75  36985.25
50%      2838.5 4519.00      0.950  70.6750  6.850   53.25 114.50  54277.00
75%      4968.5 4813.50      0.625  71.8925  4.350   59.15  66.25  81162.50
100%    21198.0 6315.00      0.500  73.6000  1.400   67.30   0.00 566432.00
```

I managed that using two `sweep`-functions and one apply function. That is ugly as heck! Is there a more elegant way?

The dataset `state.x77` is built-into R.

Comment: With elegant I mean, by using maybe one sweep and/or one apply-function? For the sake of completeness, I used a weighting vector `my_weight=c(1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)`

Comment: Can you please include minimal data (using e.g. `dput`) that allows us to reproduce your expected output.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, `state.x77` is a dataset that is built into `R`. No need to include minimal data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply each column by the respective weight in vector `my_weight`. Then take the absolute value of the result. And there is no need to define a vector of probabilities since the quartiles are already `quantile`'s default.

```
my_weight <- c(1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1)
res <- sapply(seq_along(as.data.frame(state.x77)), function(i)
  abs(quantile(state.x77[, i]* my_weight[i])))
colnames(res) <- colnames(state.x77)

res
#     Population  Income Illiteracy Life Exp Murder HS Grad  Frost      Area
#0%        365.0 3098.00      2.800  67.9600 15.100   37.80 188.00   1049.00
#25%      1079.5 3992.75      1.575  70.1175 10.675   48.05 139.75  36985.25
#50%      2838.5 4519.00      0.950  70.6750  6.850   53.25 114.50  54277.00
#75%      4968.5 4813.50      0.625  71.8925  4.350   59.15  66.25  81162.50
#100%    21198.0 6315.00      0.500  73.6000  1.400   67.30   0.00 566432.00
```

Comment: I suggest a tiny improvemet: Use `1:ncol(state.x77)` instead of `seq_along(as.data.frame(state.x77))`, that improves readability and speed. Otherwise perfect as always :)

Comment: @5th Thanks, for some reason I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I used this version because it is more flexible. In addition I recommend using `lapply` instead of `sapply` (cf. [Hadley's explanation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functionals.html#map-atomic)). You use `do.call(cbind,res)` to create a matrix or data.frame

Answer (score 1):

Why not reverse the values of your "negative"/"bad" columns (e.g., for the murder column):

```r
r=seq(0,1,0.25)
quantiles <- apply(state.x77,2,function(x) quantile(x,probs = r))
quantiles[, "Murder"] <- rev(quantiles[, "Murder"])
```

P.S. Obviously this violates the principle of one row one observation as we are altering the data... But that seems to be what you want.

Comment: thanks that leads me into the right direction. Issue with `rev` is the vectorized answer. But to my own surprise [an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39975317/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-a-dataframe-in-r/46399010#46399010) from myself works: `quantiles[,c("Illiteracy","Murder","Frost")]=quantiles[5:1,c("Illiteracy","Murder","Frost")]`. I will wait a bit if someone is trying to solve this with `sweep` or `apply` alone.